# java.lang.nullpointerexception no authentication header informatio

Tags: java, gdata, gdata-api

When I am Using the batch functionality of the GData Java client library 
getting this exception. We are able to get the feed but unable to do batch deletes.

```
 com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory$OAuthToken@259e215b
     java.lang.NullPointerException: No authentication header information
        at
     com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException.initFromAuthHeader(AuthenticationException.java:96)
        at
     com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException.<init>(AuthenticationException.java:67)
        at
     com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:608)
        at
     com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
        at
     com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
        at
     com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
        at
     com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.batch(Service.java:1454)     at
     com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.batch(GoogleService.java:770)
```

Any Help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is about accessing a null getter or setter, meaning that it doesn't exist!
So you can debug the program and see if a `NullPointerException` occurs when you try to access the getter/setter.